# Delete [sprint-boot]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I accidentally created this tag. Can someone please delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags get automatically deleted (after some time) when it does not have any question associated with it. Simply remove the tag from your question that created it and hope it will be deleted. I could not find the reference which notes the details of script execution cycle.